# Does Salesforce store user timezones in abbreviations?

Tags: apex, timezone

I need to get the timezone of the current user in Apex but I need to get the timezone abbreviation like `GMT` or `CST`. Is this possible?

Using something like this query in SOQL brings back mixed results
`Select TimeZoneSidKey from User`

I got both `GMT` and `Europe/London`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMT is Salesforce's representation of UTC and is the "timezone" used when storing date/time values in the database itself. This is NOT the same as Europe/London since GMT has no Daylight Savings.

The timezones are all stored in fields in the database based on the "identities" you can validly pass to TimeZone.getTimeZone. These SIDs are themselves driven by data stored in a picklist. These are not defined using abbreviations. You would have to provide your own mapping for that.

See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254332/how-can-i-query-the-supported-timezones-in-apex/254333#254333) for more details.